# How to initialize a global variable in a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables, mkmapview, nsnotificationcenter

I want to create a variable that all other methods can access but it needs to be initialized in a specific method first. Help?

Specifically I'm creating an NSNotification that carries this variable that I need to make global. But I don't know what the variable's value is until it is received by the method via NSNotification.

```
- (void)getWallMapViewValue:(NSNotification *)notification
{

nMapView = [notification object];


}
```

nMapView is of type MKMapView and is declared but not set a value in the .h file so it is accessible to all other methods but is null to all other methods as well.

```
@public MKMapView *nMapView;
```

**Not sure if this even can be done with a global variable so please tell me how I would go about doing it differently**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize global variables with literals or `nil`. If you do not so, they are implicitly initialized with `nil`.

If you do want to initialize them with another value, you have to do that in a piece of code that is executed at the very beginning, for example in an `+initialize` method.

BTW: Global variables are a code smell. What do you want to do in detail?

Comment: I have two view controllers. 1.) map view controller 2.) table view controller. I want to send a notification when the map view controller loads to the table view controller. The notification has the MKMapView object I need for the table view controller method. I don't know what the MKMapView object is until the notification is received in the table view controller. Do you want more code?